# jQuery update image srcs isn't working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, src

I have an option to select a theme in an iOS web app.

```
<select onchange="if(this.value)window[this.value]();">
<option value="classic">Classic</option>
<option value="gradient">Gradient</option>
</select>
```

(The `onchange` option executes the js function specified in value as soon as the option is selected, without having to submit a form.)

The javascript/jQuery...

```
    function gradient() {
        alert('Applying theme gradient...');
        $('#coff').src="/Users/William/Desktop/sasapp/icons/gradient/profile.png";
            $('#topright').src="/Users/William/Desktop/sasapp/icons/gradient/settings.png";
        $('#login').src="/Users/William/Desktop/sasapp/icons/gradient/key.png";
    }

function classic() {
    alert('Applying theme classic...');
    $('#coff').src="/Users/William/Desktop/sasapp/icons/classic/profile.png";
    $('#topright').src="/Users/William/Desktop/sasapp/icons/classic/settings.png";
    $('#login').src="/Users/William/Desktop/sasapp/icons/classic/key.png";
}
```

Basically, the above script is supposed to change the `src`s of images with the IDs `#coff` `#topright` and `#login` depending on the theme selected.

However, while the alert that the theme selected is being set is executed, the actual images stay the same and the `src`s don't change.

Comment: `$('#coff')[0].src = ...` or `$('#coff').attr('src', ...)`

Comment: Do you see .src in the jQuery documentation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `.attr()`

```
$('#coff').attr('src',"/Users/William/Desktop/sasapp/icons/gradient/profile.png");
```

- http://api.jquery.com/attr/